# How to show a specific div with its own id in jQuery when I click a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, css-selectors

I have a div like this:

```
<article id="#pippo">blablabla</article>
```

that I have hided with jQuery

```
$('article').hide();
```

now I'd like to have a link menu that show a specific article id when it's clicked for example.

If I click on link:

```
<a href="#pippo"> LINK PIPPO </a>
```

I'd like that the article named #pippo is shown

if I click on link that point to #pluto, an article with id #pluto have to be shown...

how can I do this in jQuery?

Comment: You can't have multiple element with same ID

Comment: @Munim his sample doesn't.  One is an href

Comment: @JaredPar you are right, I misread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this to work for every `<a>` tag on your page then you can do the following

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
  var id = $(this).attr('href');
  $(id).show();

  // Don't follow the link
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

More likely though you want this to work on a subset of `<a>` on the page.  If so you can distinguish them by putting a class in the link and changing your selector as appropriate

HTML:

```
<a href="#pippo" class="fakeLink"> LINK PIPPO </a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('a.fakeLink').click(function (e) {
  var id = $(this).attr('href');
  $(id).show();

  // Don't follow the link
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I've just tested the code and it worked..that's awsome thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("a").click(function(){

   $(this.href).show();

   return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

First add a class to identify the anchor tags that need this functionality, eg. 'visibility_toggle'. Then add a handler that uses the href attribute to work out which div to show/hide.

```
$('a.visibility_toggle').click(function(e) {
    $(this.href).toggle();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```